# Pandas column conversion to ints while skipping rows and headers

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've tried to research this as much a possible but have had no luck. I'm hoping I'm not missing anything to basic.

So I have a spreadsheet I need to import with pandas in python3. The main problem is my numbers are strings and I need them to be integers. The report I get is formatted strangely. First row is blank, next 7 rows have extra data I don't need and then another space on row 9. Rows 10 has the headers I want to use and the data below I need.

A couple of things I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/file.csv', skiprows=9 , converters={"Column1":int, "Column2":int, "Column3":int})
```

This returns the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Which I assume is because it is trying to convert headers.

I've also tried using the `headers` field in open_csv and get the same issue. Also a combination of headers and skiprows with no success.

Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly to import this csv in the format I need? I am also open to changing the datatype after importing the csv if that would be easier!

Thanks!

Comment: the `converters` are dict of *functions*, so you may try to replace **int** with **lambda x: int(x) if x else 0**

Comment: seems to be getting closer:

now i get this error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '128,569'` any thoughts? thank you!

Comment: So you just need to update your function to parse the int from string in several conditions, one way is to use regex replacing non digits and int() afterward

Comment: thanks, not sure how to go about that but thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)